# Make exportable private key with makecert

Tags: ssl-certificate, makecert

I need to generate a cerificate for my service given a trusted root certificate.
I tried to generate a certificate with private key:
`makecert -pe -sk Esb -iv root.pvk -n "CN=localhost" -ic root.cer -sky exchange -ss my serviceCert.cer`

This installs a certificate into my store, but when I try to export it, it says "the associated private key is marked as not exportable makecert". What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest using the "-pe" option but you already have. Maybe try the "-sv option" to output the private key as a PVK file then use pvk2pfx to make a pfx file.